# Merged projects, how to access public subs in main project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have VS 2012 with the main project as a Windows form application and an added project as a excel workbook. I have some code that are exactly the same on both projects so I am trying to save time by sharing that code.

From my excel project I added a reference to my windows form project and imported the namespace.  I can access the public functions on my main project, but I cannot seem to be able to access my public subs.

I also tried creating a module a adding a link between the projects but that would cause me to also update the code in two places. Besides, I think that creating a link may also cause some issues at deployment.

For example, in my windows form project I have the following I want to access from my second project

```
Public Sub closeXLApp()

    'This sub is called to close the application without
    'saving any changes to the workbook. The sub closes
    'the app, workbook and sheet and performs some garbage clean up
    'as well making sure that the opened Excel instance is cleared from memory.

    xlBook.Close(SaveChanges:=False)
    xlApp.Quit()

    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlSheet)
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlBook)
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp)

    xlSheet = Nothing
    xlBook = Nothing
    xlApp = Nothing

    GC.Collect()

End Sub
```

On my second project I created a reference and imported the namespace as:

```
Imports Compensation_Template_Welcome_Page
```

So when I try to access the above public sub from my second project as:

```
Private Sub btnMinCloseProject_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMinCloseProject.Click

    'This procedure runs when the btnMinCloseProject is clicked. The
    'procedure calls the function to close workbook without saving changes.

    closeXLApp()

End Sub
```

I get an error saying that the sub is not declared or not accessible due to its protection level.

Is there a better way to accomplish this? Even if is a longer route, I just want it to make it efficient in the long run.

Thanks

Comment: Please post the code of methods you cannot access.

Answer (score 0):

You're sub `closeXLApp()` is not static (shared), so you need to create an instance of the class where this sub is containted and then call the sub.